# What is the Best App to Create Gifs?

Tags: applications, animation

I have photoshop CC but it feels a bit limited.  If I want to turn a video into a gif I can, or if I want to move things around I can but what is used to create flash type effects? like bending lines or if I wanted to create animated characters what are some apps I can check out?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Hype. It doesn't do GIFs, it does HTML5 animation. But it will give you a Flash-like timeline to create vector animations that are cross-browser compatible.

Comment: can it be converted to gifs? anything else i shoudl consider?

Comment: There's another great app now called Gif Brewery that does what you're looking for.